# rolling key with two keyfobs

Tags: protocol-design

Hy i just saw this Question: [How does a rolling code work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18311/how-does-a-rolling-code-work?newreg=1920352bcffc43cdb12346aefbca6d5f)

And I just wondered how it is possible that my Vehicle (A 2013 Mazda 6) has two key fobs? As i understand this shuld not be possible. Because there shuldbe only one key that stores n+1.

Are these Vehicle using another form of a Rolling Key Algorithm or are there Keyfobs that do full handshake?(Rx+Tx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyfobs that do a handshake are actually quite common, see the HiTag2 key transponder specifics for how its handshake works.

Even without a handshake, the code can still identify the key if it is long enough, and cars can be programmed to accept multiple keys, but almost certainly there is a handshake involved.

I believe your key probably uses a Ford type transponder chip, probably transmitting at 315MHz for long range commands like door unlock, and a lower freq for engine start (123-134KHz). For engine start, the car tells the key it wants to start and adds a challenge code, then sends to the key. The key encrypts the challenge, resulting in an 80-bit code, then truncates to 40-bits and transits back with its serial number and a checksum. The car then verifies the code, and starts if it is correct.

I am not sure if the high frequency commands use the same cipher, but they are a 1-way transmission. Similar to how a garage door opener can use 2 remotes, the car can use 2 keys to unlock doors without a handshake, as internally the car will see that the code matches a programmed key.